# ASP.NET + Rabbit MQ connection and channel lifetime

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, lifetime

I see a lot of examples of usage **RabbitMq** in **.NET** (in ASP.NET or console applications). Most of them look like this:

```
using (var connecttion = MyConnectionFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateChannel())
{
   ...
}
```

Is it efficient? In [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) I see:

> AMQP connections are typically long-lived. AMQP is an application
>   level protocol that uses TCP for reliable delivery.

So I suppose it's better to have one connection for application. Another point about channels:

> AMQP 0-9-1 connections are multiplexed with channels that can be
>   thought of as "lightweight connections that share a single TCP
>   connection".

Here I suppose I can use `channel-per-request` in case of ASP.NET application. My question: is it the best practice to have `connection-per-application` and `channel-per-request`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `connection-per-application` is a suggested approach. `Channel-per-request` should do as well, but I'd test it for your required throughput. For our project we used [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/) which takes care of creating connections/channels for you. We just kept a single `MessageBus` instance for the application.